# How to get Object of custom block?

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-block

I have created a Block class as this

`class Sb_AddressManager_Block_Address_Edit extends Mage_Customer_Block_Address_Edit {....}`

and its path is

```
/www/abc/app/code/local/Sb/AddressManager/Block/Address/Edit.php
```

now I need its obj to use its functions in an other class
`class Sb_Fs_Model_Order extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order {...}`

whose  path is

`/www/abc/app/code/local/Sb/Fs/Model/Order.php`

How should I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to call the block function from model. Try the below code

```
Mage::getBlockSingleton('<your-block-alise>/address_edit')->yourFunction();
```

**Note :** Calling the block from model is not recommended.If you are going to use a same function in Block and Model. **Place that function in Helper and call where ever you want**

Comment: Why I have to use "Mage::" while it is located in local

Comment: in app/Mage.php file there is an function to call block function. Check that file.